# Identifying and debugging a getJSON error with Django

Tags: python, jquery, django

I've got an error in my Django app that I can't seem to figure out for the life of me

Basically the issue is that my getJSON call is failing in my template and I can't figure out why because I can access the url directly via the browsel and the development server is showing a 200 response as well.

Here's my view

```
def test(request):
    cases = ConfirmedCase.objects.all()
    cases = read_frame(cases, fieldnames=['provice_state', 'country_region', 'confirmedcases','date'])
    cases['date'] = pd.to_datetime(cases['date'])

    globaltrend = globaltrend.groupby('date')[['confirmedcases','1_day_growth']].sum().reset_index()
    globaltrend['date'] = globaltrend['date'].dt.date #convert back to date
    globaltrend= globaltrend.to_dict(orient='list')
    data = {}
    data['chart_data'] = globaltrend
    data = json.dumps(data,  default=str)

    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Here's the url

```
from tracker import views as tracker

urlpatterns = [
    path('test/', tracker.test, name="test"), 
]
```

If I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/ in the browser, everything works fine and I see

```
{
  "chart_data": {
    "date": [
      "2020-03-26",
      "2020-03-27"
    ],
    "confirmedcases": [
      66885,
      69030,
    ],
    "1_day_growth": [
      3.21,
      3.18,
    ],
  }
}
```

Here's my script in my template/html file

```
<script >
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = '{% url "test" %}'

            $.getJSON(url, function(d) {
                console.log("working");
                alert('yay')
            }).done(function(d) {
                console.log("done");
            }).fail(function(d) {
                console.log("error");
                console.log(url);
            }).always(function(d) {
                console.log("completed regardl");
            });

    });
</script>
```

This keeps throwing an error (and I dont see the alert), even though it is correctly console logging the url. I just can't seem to be able to successfully execute the callback

Here's my development server output on refresh

```
[29/Mar/2020 00:53:59] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1498
```

### I need this for a chart in my template. Any help would be really really appreciated

**UPDATE**

I think the error has to do with the view because when I simplify the view to the following:

```
def test(request):
    data = {"hello":[1,2,3]}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data, default=str), content_type='application/json')
```

my getJSON call starts to work in the browser (i.e. I can see the alert and success in the console log)

I can't figure out why the original view works directly via url but not via the getJSON call

Comment: Check the value of url variable on js

Comment: i did. It's fine. it's console logging correctly

Comment: Print the error passing parameters to `fail()` as in https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. It had to do with missing values in the json dump. Basically, if there are NaN or inf values in the json dump generated in the view, even though the url will correctly display the dump, querying the data via ajax will result in failure

Adding these lines to the view fixed the issue
globaltrend = globaltrend.replace(np.inf, 0) #replace inf values with 0
globaltrend = globaltrend.replace(np.NaN, 0) #replace NaN values with 0